# horizontalscrollview set child elements to fill horizontalscrollview width

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Basically I have a horizontal scroll view which, by monitoring the onTouch event I'm paging (ie:each visible part of the scroll view (page) "clicks" into the next when scrolling, rather than just having a standard `ScrollView`. see paged scrollviews in iOS).

Now I want to find a way to have inner children inherit the same width as the scrollview (which is set at `"fill_parent"`).

Here is my XML to help:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollviewbg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/content1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/content2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/content3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

As you can see the scrollview is set to width `fill_parent` and there is a `LinearLayout` inside it. Now at the moment there are three images which have a set width and height similar to the width of the screen, but what I want to do is change that for 3 `LinearLayout`s.

Each `LinearLayout` needs to inherit the same width as the scroll view, so that each one takes up a whole "page" when my code is applied, as it were.

How would I do this? Is it something I will have to do using code? What code will I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its not direct answer, but its much easier to user `ViewPager` from [Compatibility Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) for paging functionality. You can find an example in `samples` folder (see `src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.java` for source code).

Comment: that is much easier. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: I dont have that option to use support library, can we do it in scrollview

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
**android:fillViewport="true"**

```
<HorizontalScrollView

    android:fillViewport="true"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/black_border"
    android:id="@+id/displayText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

inside horizontal scroll view, i have a text view, you can try for image view

Answer (score 0):

Set all the `layout_height` parameters as `fill_parent`. You should see the image in full screen then.

Comment: WRONG! when child views are added to a `HorizontalScrollView`, `fill_parent` does not make sense.